# Select Parent where it has ALL requested children (Not just Any of them)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a search tool for my application (PHP: Laravel/Lumen, MySQL), where users can have search criteria where a parent row is returned only if it has children matching ALL IDs requested.

**Example Table Structure:**

People Table:

```
id, name, etc 
-------------------------
person123, David, ...
person888, Divya, ...
```

Interests Table:

```
id, person_id, interest_id, etc
---------------------------------
1, person123, interestABC, ...
2, person123, interestXYZ, ...
3, person888, interestABC, ...
```

**Problematic User Story**

Select Person that has `interestABC` AND `interestXYZ`

I'm able to select people that have any of the requested interests, for example:

*Select People that have any of the interests: `interestABC`, `interestXYZ`*

```
SELECT people.id FROM `people` 
INNER JOIN `people_interests` on `people`.`id` = `people_interests`.`person_id` 
WHERE `department` = "something" 
    and `people_interests`.`interest_id` in ("interestABC","interestXYZ") 
GROUP BY people.id;
```

and I can select people have any ANY interest or NO interests.

**Question**

Is there a way to do this in SQL? Or will have to do something like my IN query above and filter the results in the application code?

Comment: Hint: `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

It should be something like :

```
    SELECT people.id FROM `people` 
    INNER JOIN `people_interests` on `people`.`id` = `people_interests`.`person_id` 
    WHERE `department` = "something" 
    AND `people_interests`.`interest_id` in ("interestABC","interestXYZ")
    GROUP BY people.id
    HAVING  COUNT(people.id)>=2;
```

Comment: this will get all persons that have any of these interests but he needs all person that has both interests.

Comment: @Faesal you are right, a silly mistake but without data examples happen. Anyway I changed the query

Comment: Thank you! i wasn't very familiar with HAVING (my sql is not great) and was really stuck on how to leverage it until you updated the example. much appreciated